# chkdsk windows server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, chkdsk

I was wondering approximately how long I should expect a chkdsk on a raid 5 array with a max capacity of 300GB would take? It seems it has been on step 4 of 5 for quite a while.

Comment: Is quite a while, minutes, hours, days?  The total size isn't the only factor.  Can you give us an estimate of the number of files?  A filesystem with a large number of small files will take much longer then a filesystem with a few huge files.

Comment: my apologies: I've never had to do this on a critical machine before. There are over 100,000 files using up approximately 167 GB. I don't know the exact numbers. Quite a while in this case is about an hour and a half at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 minute per gigabyte. But I'm guessing because I have absolutely no idea about your file system, number of files, amount of data, etc..

(I use my 1 minute per gigabyte based on real-world experience of running the SQL Server `checkdb` command and backup / verify, so it's not a complete guess).

Comment: the number of files is over 100,000. We have about 167 GB of actual data on the RAID

Comment: 100 000 files isn't a lot. 167GB isn't a lot either. That said, there are factors around RAID 5 that could be making it slow.

Answer (score 0):

Depends primarily on the speed of your RAID controller & disks.  I have a 5 year old HP Proliant DL380G4 with a 800GB RAID5 Array hooked up to an HP SmartArray 6i.  The volume is about 80% full.  chkdsk took roughly an hour last time I tried, but there was nothing wrong with the volume.